# Define a custom type in a redfine schema?

Tags: xsd

I am writting a xsd schema that is redefining an other schema by using the redefine element.

Like so :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:redefine schemaLocation="some_schema.xsd">
    .....
    </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

Can someone tell me how can I define a new type in the context ?

```
<xs:simpleType name="restrictedString">
    <!-- Make a new type to be a "descendant" of string-->
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="36"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your `restrictedString` type (I assume that it's inside the `xs:redefine` block) already is a restriction of string? Please add more examples and explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: I have to restrict string because I would like to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243361/xsd-for-elements-string-with-attribute-id/24243557#24243557) but in a redefine block.

Comment: You just place the simple type inside the block. It didn't work?

Comment: In the redefine block, oXygen tells me this error : src-redefine.5.a.c: 'restriction' does not have a 'base' attribute that refers to the redefined element, ',restrictedString'. <simpleType> children of <redefine> elements must have <restriction> descendants, with 'base' attributes that refer to themselves.

Comment: Use `<xs:restriction base="restrictedString">`

Comment: Doesn't work : E [Xerces] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'restrictedString_fn3dktizrknc9pi' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the XSD files you are using. It's not possible to diagnose your problem without knowing the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was in fact quite simple.

The custom type (restrictedString) had to be specified after the redefine block :

```
<xs:schema ....>
    <xs:redefine ......>
        .....
        <use of type restrictedString>
    </xs:redefine>

    <xs:simpleType name="restrictedString">
        .... type definition
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Doing it before the redefine block or inside the redefine block doesn't works, but at the end of the document is ok.

Thanks.